# What is meant here? (async programming)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

In [this](https://eloquentjavascript.net/3rd_edition/11_async.html) book (Eloquent JS), here

```
function request(nest, target, type, content) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let done = false;
    function attempt(n) {
      nest.send(target, type, content, (failed, value) => {
        done = true;
        if (failed) reject(failed);
        else resolve(value);
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (done) return;
        else if (n < 3) attempt(n + 1);
        else reject(new Timeout("Timed out"));
      }, 250);
    }
    attempt(1);
  });
}
```

Author proceeds with saying

> It is even possible, if the request **did come through** but the **handler**
>   is just taking a bit longer, for requests to be delivered **multiple
>   times**.

I can't understand in which case author means that requests will be delivered multiple times?

I understand `send` could get called twice if it takes say 1 second for response to come but IMHO that is not the scenario the author refers to in quote, given how the quote is written (even in that case I don't see that as a problem as promise resolves only once).

---

If he refers to callback inside send function taking too long, what is the problem?

- if once request arrived that callback takes too long say 3 seconds, callback in the setTimeout won't run until code in the send callback is finished isn't it? (even though 250ms have passed).
- Once that is finished done will be true so request won't be made second time. What am I missing?

Comment: The author is just saying what you already understand: that the `send` method could be called twice. Their point is that care should be taken with the *implementation* of `send` (i.e. de handler): it should be able to deal nicely with repeated calls to `send` (i.e. requests) with the same data, even if the handler had already triggered a response for a preceding call to `send`.

Comment: @trincot I don't understand in which case can `send` be called twice; well I have one scenario which I stated in question but I doubt that is the same scenario referred to in (book) authors quote

Comment: If the implementation of `send` needs to wait for something to happen (a database transaction to finish, ...etc), it might take a longer time to call the callback. *During* that waiting time the timer in this code may expire and `send` is called again. The implementation of `send` might just have been ready and called the callback for the preceding request, and needs now to deal with the same request again. So it will call the callback again.

Comment: @trincot you must read my question once more maybe. the situation you describe is the one I mention in the bottom of my question also, isn't it? The problem is the scenario author refers to in quote (when send can be called twice), isn't I think the same scenario that me and you talk about - at least the way he put it in English. e.g. he is talking about "handler is just taking a bit longer" instead he had to say then that "request is talking longer to arrive"

Comment: Yes it is that situation, and it is also what the author is aware of and expanding on. It matches their word use of "request", "coming back", "handler", ...etc.

Comment: @trincot Yeah in that case I would expect him instead of saying "handler is just taking a bit longer"(which hints that code inside send is taking long), to say smth like "request is taking long to arrive"

Comment: These phrases are essentially saying the same thing. If the request is taking long to arrive, it is because the handler is busy with it for a long time. This does not mean the *synchronous* code in `send` is taking long, but that also the handler (exposing the `send` method) needs to get asynchronous answers from lower level components like a database before it can trigger the response. So in that sense, the handler is indeed busy.

Comment: @trincot for me when I say that "request takes long to arrive" I imply that code inside handler hasn't been run yet, while what author said for me implies request did come, but the code inside handler is taking too long. do you see the difference?(or what confused me? :))

Comment: @trincot I saw your edit, I think after edit we are more on the same page.

Comment: What to you is the "handler"? I think we may be interpreting that differently?

Comment: @trincot Check my last comment I think we are now on same page. When author said "handler is just taking a bit longer" I thought code _inside_ the callback of `send` function is taking long to complete.

Comment: If that is what the Author intended (the handler is the callback), which could well be the case, then it doesn't make sense. Whether the callback executes fast or slow does not influence whether a next callback will still be triggered or not. I guess the author is the only one that can shed more light on this...

Comment: @trincot Yeah that was the reason why I asked this question, you can see that in initial version of my question I too said that in case he refers to callback as handler that doesn't make sense, as that shouldn't reflect on how many times send is called; I couldn't find his email maybe if someone encounters this who also know his twitter or smth and is interested can forward this question otherwise be it as it is.

Comment: @trincot I will bring question to original form to show you that I too had same confusion as you in last comment

Answer (score 0):

The author doesn't refer to the callback passed to *send* as the handler. The handler is what deal with your request on the server, so to speak. The fourth parameter in *send* is a function to call by the handler when reasponse comes in and all the work needed is done.

Before firing off a request, you should make it sure **crow-tech**, particulary each nest, supports its type. Therefore, you should define a handler for a certain type of request using *defineRequestType* exported the the **crow-tech** inferface:

```
defineRequestType(
    note,
    function handler() { }
);
```

> Crow nest computers are built to communicate using request-response
> pairs. Each request is tagged with a type, which determines how it is
> handled. You must define handlers for specific request types. When a
> request comes in, its handler is called to produce a response. But to
> make nests capable of receiving that request, we first have to define
> a request type named "note".

Since "Networks are hard", there might be occasions when requests, being sent, don't arrive due to some obstacles interfering. That is why you should send off a request 3 times before giving up, which is *somewhat arbitrary*, as the author puts it.

> To communicate with other devices, these machines use light signals (a
> sequence of quick flashes). This means that only nests that have an
> unbroken visual connection can communicate.

If the nest is unavailable, a request will be fired off three times before giving up and timing out.

If the nest is available, your request "*will come through*". In this case, the handler might take longer doing whatever it needs than what was previously defined as "*somewhat arbitrary*" — your code is still retrying not knowing whether the request "*did come through*" and is being handled.

Sometimes, the handler's job might be done just in time, before the timeout, and the first response is sent back, then the handler follows its routine for the other two attempts. Since the promise is already resolved, there is nothing to fret about, but *we keep that in mind*.

You can simulate "taking too long" like this and see what the output will be:

```
const TAKING_TOO_LONG = Symbol("taking too long");

requestType(
    TAKING_TOO_LONG,
    async function handlerForTakingTooLong(nest) {
        await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 700));
        return `Here is your response, ${nest.name}`;
    }
);

request(bigOak, "Cow Pasture", TAKING_TOO_LONG, "test message")
    .then(console.log);
```